# Controls not recognized when no masterpage implemented

Tags: asp.net, .net, textbox, master-pages

Hi I am trying to create a single webforms page, but I do not want this specific page to inherit from a master page. The problem is that if I don't reference one, the `asp` tag isn't getting recognized and i can't seem to use any of the controls like `<asp:TextBox />`. Is there a way I can use these controls without having to reference a master page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If you do not use a master page, then you need to register the system.web assembly on your aspx page or in the web.config.

Answer (score 2):

the `<asp:` prefix has nothing to do with the master page.  It should work fine without a master page.  There could be an alternative problem that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a Web Form on your project it should possible to use asp elements.

Anyway, you can create a simple master page and then use it for your pages that you don't want to use the default master page.